# Returning numbers but they are printing as 0

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, printing, return

Ok so I have this program I've been working on that requires using recursive methods and the array numbers must be an array not an ArrayList. The purpose of the program is to allow users to enter doubles until they type 0. The doubles must be stored into an array and I must use recursive methods to find the max, the number of negative numbers, and the sum of positive numbers. The problem I am having is when the program exits and it prints the results it is printing the max and sums as 0 instead of the answer. I have tried just about everything I could think of and can't get it to work. If someone could please tell me what my problem is it would be appreciated...Thanks.

note: At first I put max, negative, and sum in the assignment9 method and also tried printing from the main method but nothing seems to work.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;;

public class Assignment9 {

//main method initializes variables then calls method assignment9
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Double> help = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double max = 0;
    int negative = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    assignment9(help, count, max, negative, sum);

}//end main

//adds user input to array until 0 is entered; it then calls other methods
public static void assignment9(ArrayList<Double> help, int count, double max, int negative, double sum)
{
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double input;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    input = scan.nextInt();

    if (input == 0)
    {
        double[] numbers = new double[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = help.get(i);
        }
        findMax(numbers, count-1, max);
        countNegative(numbers, count-1, negative);
        computeSumPositive(numbers, count-1, sum);

    }else{
            help.add(input);
            count++;
            assignment9(help, count, max, negative, sum);
    }//end if
    System.out.println("The maximum number is " + fmt.format(max));
    System.out.println("The total number of negative numbers is " + negative);
    System.out.println("The sum of positive numbers is " + fmt.format(sum));
    System.exit(0);

}//end assignment9

//compares elements of array to find the max until count = -1
public static double findMax(double[] numbers, int count, double max)
{

    if (count == -1)
    {
        return max;
    }else if(numbers[count] > max){
        max = numbers[count];
        count--;
        findMax(numbers, count, max);
    }//end if
    return max;

}//end findMax

public static int countNegative(double[] numbers, int count, int negative)
{

    if(count == -1)
    {
        return negative;
    }else if(numbers[count] < 0){
        negative++;
        count--;
        countNegative(numbers, count, negative);
    }
    return negative;
}//end countNegative

public static double computeSumPositive(double[] numbers, int count, double sum)
{
     if(count == -1)
     {
         return sum;
     }else{
         sum = sum + numbers[count];
         count--;
         computeSumPositive(numbers, count, sum);
         return sum;
     }
}//end computeSumPositive

}//end class
```

Comment: Does "I have tried just about everything I could think of" include using a debugger?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is...I'm pretty new to programming but i pressed in eclipse run then debug on the top

Comment: That's the next thing you should do - even if tieTYT's answer solves your problem... ;-) If using eclipse, read this: http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/.

Answer (score 1):

When you print out the values in the line that says

```
System.out.println("The maximum number is " + fmt.format(max));
```

You never assign the `max` variable to anything in the `assignment9` method.  Sure, you may call `findMax`, but you never say `max = findMax(...)` before that.  Since you called it in the `main` by passing in 0, that's the thing it prints out.

Your max function has some sort of other bug in it, but this is the reason it's always printing 0.

Comment: Ok that fixed most of my problems but for some reason when I add a negative number the max comes out to be 0 but if I add only positives it gives the right answer.

Comment: This did not give me the right answer: `Sandbox.findMax(new double[]{6,2,3,4,5}, 4, 0)`

Comment: Yea sometimes it gives right answers and sometimes wrong answers...i fixed sum of positive integers to only add the positives but I'm not sure what else is wrong. Do i have to say max= findMax(...) in the findMax method as well? And I also got the countNegative to work. The only problem now is the max and sum are not getting the right answers all the time

Comment: Scratch that I fixed everything...there was no alternative to if the element of the array way less than max, etc. Thanks everyone